# Why using "--requirements_file" uploads dependencies onto GCS?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I'm currently generating a template with those parameters:

```
        --runner DataflowRunner \
        --requirements_file requirements.txt \
        --project ${GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID} \
        --output ${GENERATED_FILES_PATH}/staging \
        --staging_location=${GENERATED_FILES_PATH}/staging \
        --temp_location=${GENERATED_FILES_PATH}/temp \
        --template_location=${GENERATED_FILES_PATH}/templates/calculation-template \
```

and the SDK is uploading dependencies specified inside `requirements.txt` onto GCS inside the staging section. I do not understand... For me using this kind of file would allow workers to directly pull dependencies from the official pip registry, not from my GCS, right?

It makes running this command very long since it needs to upload packages :/

Any explanation why is it happening? Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is done to make the Dataflow worker startup process more efficient and consistent (both initially and when auto-scaling). Without this, each time a Dataflow worker starts up, that worker has to directly connect to PyPI to find the latest matching versions of dependencies. Instead of this, set of dependencies are staged at pipeline initiation and are consistently installed in workers throughout the pipeline execution.

Comment: Is this behavior guaranteed?  I don't see it mentioned in the docs.  This implementation, where dependencies are staged to GCS rather than pulled from the internet, has ramifications for the networking capabilities of Dataflow workers.